# `window.removeEventListener('keydown')` doesn't work in react hooks function

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react` hooks inside a stateless component. Below is the source code:

```
const MyComp = ({focused}) => {
...
const keyPressListener = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.log('key press:', e);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (focused) {
      console.log('add event listener');
      window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressListener);
    } else {
      console.log('remove event listener');
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPressListener);
    }
  }, [focused]);
...
}
```

It listens on the property `focused`. It adds keydown listener when it is true and remove it when it becomes false. I can see the console log about `add/remove event listener` but the `keyPressListener` function is still called after remove. I see many people have the same issue because they didn't bind the function. But I don't think it is needed for arrow function in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the value of `focused` prop changes, `MyComp` re-renders. On each re-render, a new `keyPressListener` function is created. This new function is either added or removed from the `keypress` event by the `useEffect` hook.

So, what is removed from the `keypress` event is not the **previously added** `keyPressListener` but a newly created function which wasn't even added previously.
The end result is that the original `keyPressListener` stays added to the `keypress` event.

### Solution 1

You move the `keyPressListener` can be moved out of the `MyComp`. This was the same function will be referenced for the addition and removal from the `keypress` event.

### Solution 2

You can memoize the `keyPressListener` function so that the same function can be added and removed from the `keypress` event. Since you are using hooks you can go ahead with **useMemo** or **useCallback**

```
const MyComp = ({ focused }) => {
  const keyPressListener = ({ code }) => {
    console.log('key press:', code);
  };

  const memoizedListener = useMemo(() => keyPressListener, []);
  // or use 
  // const memoizedListener = useCallback(keyPressListener, []);

  console.log('rendered again');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focused) {
      console.log('add event listener');
      window.addEventListener('keydown', memoizedListener);
    } else {
      console.log('remove event listener');
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', memoizedListener);
    }
  }, [focused, memoizedListener]);

  return <h1>Test component</h1>;
};
```

Hope this helps you understand the working of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching EventListener in useEffect hooks usually needs "cleanup". Rewrite your `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (focused) {
    console.log('add event listener');
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressListener);
  }
  return () => {
    console.log('remove event listener');
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPressListener);
  };
}, [focused]);
```

You may also use `useRef` hook to contain the event listener callback to remove on cleanup.